# @RequestMapping not mapping correctly

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to setup a controller and am unfortunately not able to view the output... everything is rendering correctly.  When I go to `http://localhost:8080/CMT/content/edit` I get a 404 page.  Running my app from Netbeans goes to `http://localhost:8080/CMT`

```
package com.cmt.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Content {

    @RequestMapping(value="/content/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(Model model) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

**app-config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <!-- Scans the classpath of this application for @Components to deploy as beans -->
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.cmt" />
    <!-- Configures the @Controller programming model -->
    <mvc:annotation-driven />
    <!-- Resolves view names to protected .jsp resources within the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

How can I debug this and see what is working and what isn't?

**Update**

The GlassFish server log in Netbeans shows

```
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1531ed: defining beans [content,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,viewResolver]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@b91162
INFO: Mapped URL path [/content/edit] onto handler [com.cmt.controllers.Content@1f3e27b]
INFO: Mapped URL path [/content/edit.*] onto handler [com.cmt.controllers.Content@1f3e27b]
INFO: Mapped URL path [/content/edit/] onto handler [com.cmt.controllers.Content@1f3e27b]
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet': initialization completed in 1234 ms
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [CMT] at [/CMT]
INFO: CMT was successfully deployed in 3,725 milliseconds.
```

Comment: Is your servlet in web.xml configured properly ?

Comment: Is commons logging telling you anything? Do you have a file named index.jsp in your /WEB-INF/jsp/ folder? What does your web.xml look like?

Comment: @smp7d - I added the web.xml and yes, I do have an index.jsp in my jsp folder.

Comment: So, is commons logging telling you anything? Have you debugged to ensure that you are getting into your controller method? You may be getting a 404 on your initial request or when you dispatch to your jsp.

Comment: @smp7d - I'm actually not sure how to do that... what terms should I google to find out how to do that?

Comment: Look at adding log4j to your project (http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/) so that you can see what Spring is trying to tell you - if it just cant find the jsp, you will see this in log. Debug in your IDE to see if you are getting to your controller method.

Comment: I believe it is advised to post you solution as an answer in such cases so as to help distinguish this site from a help forum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your `DispatcherServlet` named `app` mapped to `/*` in `web.xml`? From your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690211) question I see:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring MVC Dispatcher Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

`/content/edit` URL does not match `*.htm` pattern. Try `/content/edit.htm` for a possible workaround.

Comment: Great catch!!  I tried using `/*` instead of `*.htm` with no luck.  I'd prefer not to require .htm on the URLs and just avoid a file extension altogether.