# URI mapping not accessible

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Netbeans... in the Glassfish server log I see

```
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/app-config.xml]
INFO: JSR-250 'javax.annotation.ManagedBean' found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Named' annotation found and supported for component scanning
INFO: JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@1531ed: defining beans [content,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalPersistenceAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping#0,org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter#0,org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.MappedInterceptor#0,viewResolver]; parent: org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@b91162
INFO: Mapped URL path [/content/edit] onto handler [com.cmt.controllers.Content@1f3e27b]
INFO: Mapped URL path [/content/edit.*] onto handler [com.cmt.controllers.Content@1f3e27b]
INFO: Mapped URL path [/content/edit/] onto handler [com.cmt.controllers.Content@1f3e27b]
INFO: Instantiated an instance of org.hibernate.validator.engine.resolver.JPATraversableResolver.
INFO: FrameworkServlet 'Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet': initialization completed in 1234 ms
INFO: WEB0671: Loading application [CMT] at [/CMT]
INFO: CMT was successfully deployed in 3,725 milliseconds.
```

which shows that `/content/edit` is being mapped to my controller as specified here:

```
package com.cmt.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class Content {

    @RequestMapping(value="/content/edit", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView edit(Model model) {
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.setViewName("index");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

When I go to that page I continue to see a 404 error.  It's showing it has registered the mapping, why wouldn't this be working?

My **web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/app-config.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

I've used URLs `http://localhost:8080/content/edit` and `http://localhost:8080/CMT/content/edit`

Comment: Duplicate of [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690628/requestmapping-not-mapping-correctly) - resolved there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your urls don't match your url-pattern which requires html extention. So I suspect this is the problem

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Spring-MVC-Dispatcher-Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: As Oleg says: your dispatcher servlet only listens for `*.htm`, so `/content/edit` won't match. Try `/content/edit.htm` or change the servlet mapping.

Comment: Is it possible to not have a file extension?  So my URL would just be `/content/edit` instead of `/content/edit.htm` ?

Comment: Sure, it just says which urls will be handled by DispatcherServlet, so I think you can use <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> instead.