# fail in transmitting data in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to make a vote page. When I click the "", the amount of vote plus but now it meets with "404 not found".(There is no vote2.jsp in my project because I only want to refresh part of the page.)

```
vote.jsp
<body>
<div class="testSpan" data-id="1"><span>vote for A</span>  num:<em>0</em></div>
<div class="testSpan" data-id="2"><span>vote for B</span> num:<em>0</em></div>
<div class="testSpan" data-id="3"><span>vote for C</span> num:<em>0</em></div>
<div class="testSpan" data-id="4"><span>vote for D</span> num:<em>0</em></div>
</body>
ajax:
    $(".testSpan").click(function(){
    var xsId = $(this).attr("data-id");
    $.post("/vote/vote2",{
        xsId:xsId
    },function(data, textStatus){
        var xsMap = data.xsMap;
        $(".testSpan").each(function(){
            var id = $(this).attr("data-id");
            $(this).find("em").html(xsMap[id]);
        });
    }, "json");
});

Controller:
    @RequestMapping(value="/vote/vote2")
public net.sf.json.JSONObject vote(int xsId){
    net.sf.json.JSONObject json = new net.sf.json.JSONObject();
    userService.vote(xsId);
    json.put("xsMap", UserServiceImpl.xsMap);
    return json;
}
```

Comment: See in network tab on debug panel wich url is requesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need not have to create `vote2.jsp` file. Also the error is valid, as you haven't specified context path in AJAX URL request.

To solve this problem.

1. Use developer tools of the browser and locate the URL raised by
   AJAX.
2. The URL should include context path.
3. Verify DispatcherServlet settings (in case you are using Spring). Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9690628/requestmapping-not-mapping-correctly).

Comment: The context path is "/vote".It print "POST localhost:8080/vote/vote2 404 (Not Found)" so "localhost:8080/vote/vote2"  is raised.Part of dispatcherServlet settings is "<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>" and I have tested it.

Comment: What is the context path of your web app? That should also be the part of requesting URL. Note that in request mapping you are already mentioning `/vote/vote2.jsp`. So the URL for ajax should be `/vote/vote/vote2,jsp` (assuming your context path is `/vote`)

Comment: Finally I add "@responsebody" in front of vote then it do help